# Whitelist allowed IPs (in/out) using iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, blacklist

I have a few ip ranges to which I want my server to able to connect and  users to connect from. Everything else should be blocked.

How should I do that with iptables?

My OS is Debian based linux distribution.

Answer (score 31):

I'd suggest grabbing a firewall configuration tool, such a [Firestarter](https://sourceforge.net/projects/firestarter/), and going from there. Here are some basics for you, though.

```
#Flush existing rules
iptables -F
# Allow existing connections to continue
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Accept everything from the 192.168.1.x network
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
# Allow connections from this host to 192.168.2.10
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -d 192.168.2.10 -j ACCEPT
# Set up default DROP rule for eth0
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Comment: You know you can format your code in serverfault posts, using the 101010 button.
That way your comments won't come out as shouting.
Just select (drag your mouse over) the code and then click the 101010 button above the text field.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I didn't realize that. Now I know :)

Comment: +1 for EXISTING,RELATED - too many people don't do this.

Comment: +1, how do you indicate allowed port as well? Is that the part that has "iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT"   the /24? Thanks!

Comment: I think the /24 is the [network mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation)

Comment: For the love of god, please set the default DROP rule LAST! I locked myself (and everything else!) out of a machine by following that order of operations.

Comment: Terrible answer. OP says nothing about dropping all current connections. Now I'm locked out because I assumed the top answer made sense.

Comment: This is why I love serial access to cloud servers... I've locked myself out due to out of disk space, sshd misconfiguration and losing keys. Having had iptables related lockouts, yet.

Answer (score 17):

```
iptables -I INPUT -s <allowed_ip> -j ACCEPT #(repeat this line as needed)
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

This will turn your system into a non-existent system for non-allowed computers.

Comment: Note that blindly applying this these and other comparable rules can interfere with the popular `sudo` command, which may fail when it cannot resolve the local host. This can be mitigated by specifying the externally-facing interface with `-i` or explicitly allowing access from `lo`.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to allow arbitrary ranges rather than entire subnets, you can use the 'iprange' iptables module:

`iptables -P INPUT DROP`

`iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.30-50 -j ACCEPT`

for example, will allow traffic coming from all machines with addressess between 192.168.1.30 and 192.168.1.50.

If you want to allow incoming and outgoing traffic to the same range of IP's, I'd suggest that you create a specific chain allowing that IPs and targeting all the input and output target to it:

--define the default policies to drop everithing:

`iptables -P INPUT DROP`

`iptables -P OUTPUT DROP`

--create the new chain:

`iptables -N allowed_ips`

--if the source is part of the allowed range, accept

`iptables -A allowed_ips -m iprange --src-range 192.168.1.30-50 -j ACCEPT`

--if not, return to the caller chain to continue processing

`iptables -A allowed_ips -j RETURN`

--make all traffic entering and leaving the machine go through our new chain

`iptables -A INPUT -j allowed_ips`

`iptables -A OUTPUT -j allowed_ips`

and that's it! of course you may need aditional rules, such as one allowing all traffic from/to the lo interface, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Once you are happy with your rules, [you probably want to save them](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Restoring_iptables_Automatically_On_Boot). The comments in this link have several options on how to do that.

An easy to use iptables rules generator for simple needs is [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Uncomplicated_Firewall_ufw).
The package is available in debian unstable.

Also try [Firestarter](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firestarter). Available in lenny.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [ferm](http://ferm.foo-projects.org/) which I also use for the past year and has helped me a lot with cases such as conditional firewall rules.