# How to allow a range of IP's with IPTABLES?

Tags: iptables

Here is my iptables, how can I make it so that I can allow a range of ip's on ETH1 (10.51.x.x)

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.4 on Thu Jul  8 13:00:14 2010
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 ! -i lo -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7 
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT 
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN 
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you only want to allow a certain range of IP addresses inside of 10.50.0.0 (such as from 10.50.10.20 through 10.50.10.80) you can use the following command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m iprange --src-range 10.50.10.20-10.50.10.80 -j ACCEPT
```

If you want to allow the entire range you can use this instead:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -s 10.50.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
```

See [iptables man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) and this question here on ServerFault:  [Whitelist allowed IPs (in/out) using iptables](https://serverfault.com/questions/30026/whitelist-allowed-ips-in-out-using-iptables)

Comment: Where do I put this line?

Comment: Those are the commands that you would run from the command line:  
[root@host ~]# iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -s 10.50.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT

Comment: Use "10.50.10.20-10.50.10.80", ["-80" might not do what you want](http://blog.capitar.com/iptables-ip-range-reversed/).

Comment: @runlevelsix If I wanted to allow for an ip range like 10.0.0.0 thru 10.255.255.255, would I use 10.0.0.0/24 ?

Comment: @MikeCurry  this is specifying what to run on the command -line/from your terminal. Alternatively, you can add this rule to an iptables rules file in /etc/iptables/rulesets.d (if you're using Debian Linux) by removing the "iptables " and following space from the line: -A INPUT -i eth1 -m iprange --src-range 10.50.10.20-10.50.10.80 -j ACCEPT.

Comment: @RoboBear that particular IP range is 10.0.0.0/8

Comment: Is it possible to define a discontinued range?

Answer (score 4):

For a specific port, say 22:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  -m iprange --src-range  10.50.10.20-10.50.10.80  --dport 22  -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you did saw what you want to allow those IPs for but 10.51.x.x in CIDR translates to `10.50.0.0/16`.  So it will be something like the line for the loopback interface that has `127.0.0.0/8`.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m iprange --src-range 10.50.10.20-80 -j ACCEPT
```

May give the following error:

```
iptables: Applying firewall rules: xt_iprange: range 10.50.10.20-80 is reversed and will never match
```

To correct this just put the full ip instead like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m iprange --src-range 10.50.10.20-10.50.10.80 -j ACCEPT
```

Ref.:http://blog.capitar.com/iptables-ip-range-reversed/