# Getting iptables to allow one network only

Tags: debian, iptables

I'm setting up a local server for use internally at the office. It is running Debian Squeeze 64-bit.

We have two networks, 192.168.1.0/24 for our employees and 192.168.2.0/24 for guests. What I'm trying to do is make the firewall reject all traffic, except for incoming connections on port 22 and 80 on the employee network only. Using the configuration below does not help, I am still able to access the server both by ssh and http from the guest network. I am completely sure the machines on the guest network is connected to the guest network only. I am also sure the firewall rules are active since iptables -L lists them accordingly.

I've compared with other posts here on serverfault, such as [How to allow a range of IP's with IPTABLES?](https://serverfault.com/questions/161401/how-to-allow-a-range-of-ips-with-iptables) but I don't see how it differs from my own.

This is my current configuration.

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [444:43563]
:INPUT ACCEPT [444:43563]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [402:144198]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [402:144198]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT DROP [1:242]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:LOG_DROP - [0:0]
:LOG_ACCEPT - [0:0]
:icmp_packets - [0:0]

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j icmp_packets
-A INPUT -j DROP

-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j icmp_packets
-A OUTPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Any ideas why it's not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what your PREROUTING rules are doing and why they are repeated several times?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure. I copied the config off from a template that I'm using for some other web-servers. The only things I've changed are the INPUT/OUTPUT rules. You are welcome to suggest changes. :-)

Comment: Late reply, but I now have an answer to your comment James. The technician from whom I originally copied the configuration from just confirmed that it was an error on his part. So they are not repeated for any logic reason. Well spotted! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was!

Turns out that the way our network is setup, all guest traffic is routed through a common ip onto our normal network, so to the server all traffic from the guest network appeared to be coming from a host on the normal network. What I did was create the following inbound rule and made sure to put it before any other inbound rule. This is what the new file looks like:

```
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [444:43563]
:INPUT ACCEPT [444:43563]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [402:144198]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [402:144198]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,PSH,URG -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j DROP
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT DROP [1:242]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:LOG_DROP - [0:0]
:LOG_ACCEPT - [0:0]
:icmp_packets - [0:0]

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.27 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j icmp_packets
-A INPUT -j DROP

-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s 192.168.1.27 -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -j icmp_packets
-A OUTPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

That solved it. :-)

Comment: Great that you found the answer yourself. Remember to come back tomorrow and mark your answer as accepted. :)

Comment: Yes, I attempted to do so before but it told me I had to wait two days. Will do. Thanks. :-)