# limit ip Masquerade to certain ip range

Tags: iptables, nat, masquerade

I'm using the entire 10.0.0.0/8 subnet on the private side.

I want to allow a certain section of the subnet (say 10.0.0.2 - 10.0.31.254) to access the internet via linux router but not the rest of the network(10.0.32.1 - 10.255.255.254)

I have tried iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/19 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
10.0.0.0/19 is 10.0.0.2 - 10.0.31.254
  but with that none of the workstations can access the net

I know the entire 10.0.0.0/8 is 16,777,214 ip addresses but I have my reasons

Thankyou

Comment: Your problem description is not helpful for two reasons. First, you only show a portion of the `iptables` rule that didn't work. Second, you don't tell us exactly what went wrong when you tried it, just that it didn't work.

Comment: Can you give us the full iptables rule(s) you are using?  `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/19` is incomplete.

Comment: the full rule was:  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/19 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
as for not working all i can elaborate on is the workstations no longer could access the internet

Comment: Is eth0 the WAN-facing interface?

Comment: yes eth0 is wan eth1 is lan

Comment: I;m trying to figure out how to allow my wrkstations (current 27 of them) to access the net through my backbone but not clients who vpn in and are on the lan (to access servers for maintenence etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out via this question [How to allow a range of IP's with IPTABLES?](https://serverfault.com/questions/161401/how-to-allow-a-range-of-ips-with-iptables)

its:

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m iprange --src-range (start ip)-(end ip) -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

example:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.2-10.0.31.255 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different syntax on ubuntu 22.04 that worked for me

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s <network eg 192.168.0.0/16> -o <interface eg ens160> -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score -5):

Squid is a caching proxy for the Web supporting HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, and more.

```
  http://www.squid-cache.org/
```

You can write ACL in squid and allow/disallow on the basis of your requirement.

Comment: I am not against squid, but it isn't a NAT tool.  If he needs to use applications that cannot operate via a HTTP/TCP proxy, then squid will not be the answer he needs.  His question was about iptables, and what he wants should be trivial, but he hasn't povided enough information.

Comment: I need full nat

Comment: and I'm a she not a he :)