# How to whitelist CloudFlare IP ranges within iptables rules (multiport)?

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables, blacklist, whitelist

There seem to be many different ways to setup whitelist rules within iptables.

What is the wisest way to whitelist the CloudFlare IP address ranges below via SSH?

```
204.93.240.0/24 (204.93.240.0 - 204.93.240.255)
204.93.177.0/24 (204.93.177.0 - 204.93.177.255)
199.27.128.0/21 (199.27.128.0 - 199.27.135.255)
173.245.48.0/20 (173.245.48.0 - 173.245.63.255)
103.22.200.0/22 (103.22.200.0 - 103.22.203.255)
141.101.64.0/18 (141.101.64.0 - 141.101.127.255)
108.162.192.0/18 (108.162.192.0 - 108.162.255.255)
190.93.240.0/20 (190.93.240.0 - 190.93.255.255)
188.114.96.0/20 (188.114.96.0 - 188.114.255.255)
```

According to their FAQ it should be done as follows:

`iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s CLOUDFLARE_IP_RANGE -j ACCEPT`

However, this generates the following error:

`Bad argument 'http,https'`

It also does not provide for OUTPUT rules, or rules to be flushed first.

Comment: The following thread may be helpful: [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/30026/whitelist-allowed-ips-in-out-using-iptables)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never seen anyone try to use service names in that argument. Try using the equivalent numeric port numbers instead:

```
--dports 80,443
```